# How to apply window case-when functions on pandas groups

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I have a table with two identifier columns `w` and `x`. The columns `y` brings order to the column `z`, which is the destination variable. Every sequence identified by `w` and `x` has at least two rows and all distinct values in `z`. I want to count for each of the `z`s how often they occur in the sequences in which position. Position-wise I'm interested in whether it's the first, last or any other.
My approach in R's `dplyr`is the following (for those unfamiliar with `%>%`, it's the pipe operator that takes the left hand output and puts it as first argument into the right hand function, you can read it as "and then"):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)

data <- tribble(
  ~w,   ~x,  ~y,   ~z,
   1,    1,    1,  "a",
   1,    1,    2,  "b",
   1,    2,    1,  "b",
   1,    2,    2,  "a",
   1,    2,    3,  "c",
   1,    2,    4,  "d",
   2,    1,    1,  "b",
   2,    1,    2,  "a",
   2,    1,    3,  "c",
   2,    1,    4,  "d"
)
```

First I add a sequence index to each ordered `w` and `x` groups and a marker that determine the categorical position of `z` in the sequence from it (the `position_in_sequence`).

```
data_with_markers <- 
  data %>%
  group_by(w, x) %>%
  arrange(y, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(
    sequence_id = row_number(),
    position_in_sequence = case_when(
      sequence_id == first(sequence_id) ~ "first",
      sequence_id == last(sequence_id) ~ "last",
      TRUE ~ "other" # this is the "else"
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()


>data_with_markers
# A tibble: 10 x 6
       w     x     y z     sequence_id position_in_sequence 
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <int> <chr>
 1     1     1     1 a               1 first
 2     1     1     2 b               2 last 
 3     1     2     1 b               1 first
 4     1     2     2 a               2 other
 5     1     2     3 c               3 other
 6     1     2     4 d               4 last 
 7     2     1     1 b               1 first
 8     2     1     2 a               2 other
 9     2     1     3 c               3 other
10     2     1     4 d               4 last
```

Then I do a simple count by the `position_in_sequence` and `z`.

```
data_summary <- data_with_markers %>% 
  group_by(position_in_sequence, z) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup()

> data_summary
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  position_in_sequence  z         n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 first a         1
2 first b         2
3 last  b         1
4 last  d         2
5 other a         2
6 other c         2
```

For pandas, I'm stuck with getting the `position_in_sequence` variable (I'm using the `reticulate` package here):

```
import pandas as pd
data = r.data
data

     w    x    y  z
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a
1  1.0  1.0  2.0  b
2  1.0  2.0  1.0  b
3  1.0  2.0  2.0  a
4  1.0  2.0  3.0  c
5  1.0  2.0  4.0  d
6  2.0  1.0  1.0  b
7  2.0  1.0  2.0  a
8  2.0  1.0  3.0  c
9  2.0  1.0  4.0  d

data_sorted = data.sort_values(['w', 'x', 'y'])

data_sorted['sequence_id'] = data_sorted.groupby(['w', 'x']).cumcount() + 1
data_sorted

     w    x    y  z  sequence_id
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a            1
1  1.0  1.0  2.0  b            2
2  1.0  2.0  1.0  b            1
3  1.0  2.0  2.0  a            2
4  1.0  2.0  3.0  c            3
5  1.0  2.0  4.0  d            4
6  2.0  1.0  1.0  b            1
7  2.0  1.0  2.0  a            2
8  2.0  1.0  3.0  c            3
9  2.0  1.0  4.0  d            4
```

I fiddled around with `.apply` but I would need to access the column `sequence_id` at a certain row and the column's min and max at the same time to compare, but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: how do you come up with the sequence id in relation to x and w. I just havent understood you

Comment: the elements in `z` can appear anywhere in a sequence. `a` could be first in one and last in the other, or an intermediate element in even another sequence. Their order is governed by the column `y`

Comment: That doesnt still answer the question. What is first and what is last. Are they determined by order of ranking after sort or are they the min and max values respectively?

Comment: "Their order is governed by the column y", hence the sort in both versions

Comment: what determines categories first, last and other?

Comment: " I want to count for each of the zs how often they occur in the sequences in which position. Position-wise I'm interested in whether it's the first, last or any other. "

Answer (score 1):

You can do it exactly as you did in R with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) in python:

```py
>>> from datar.all import (
...     f, tribble, group_by, arrange, row_number, 
...     case_when, first, last, ungroup, mutate, count
... )
>>> 
>>> data = tribble(
...    f.w,  f.x,  f.y, f.z,
...    1,    1,    1,   "a",
...    1,    1,    2,   "b",
...    1,    2,    1,   "b",
...    1,    2,    2,   "a",
...    1,    2,    3,   "c",
...    1,    2,    4,   "d",
...    2,    1,    1,   "b",
...    2,    1,    2,   "a",
...    2,    1,    3,   "c",
...    2,    1,    4,   "d"
... )
>>> 
>>> data_with_markers = (
...     data >>
...     group_by(f.w, f.x) >>
...     arrange(f.y, _by_group=True) >>
...     mutate(
...         sequence_id=row_number(),
...         position_in_sequence=case_when(
...             f.sequence_id == first(f.sequence_id), "first",
...             f.sequence_id == last(f.sequence_id),  "last",
...             True, "other"
...         )
...     ) >>
...     ungroup()
... )
>>> 
>>> data_with_markers
        w       x       y        z  sequence_id position_in_sequence
  <int64> <int64> <int64> <object>      <int64>             <object>
0       1       1       1        a            1                first
1       1       1       2        b            2                 last
2       1       2       1        b            1                first
3       1       2       2        a            2                other
4       1       2       3        c            3                other
5       1       2       4        d            4                 last
6       2       1       1        b            1                first
7       2       1       2        a            2                other
8       2       1       3        c            3                other
9       2       1       4        d            4                 last
>>> 
>>> data_summary = (
...   data_with_markers >>
...   group_by(f.position_in_sequence, f.z) >>
...   count() >>
...   ungroup()
... )
>>>   
>>> data_summary
  position_in_sequence        z       n
              <object> <object> <int64>
0                first        a       1
1                first        b       2
2                 last        b       1
3                 last        d       2
4                other        a       2
5                other        c       2
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.

Comment: pretty cool, thanks! I've seen some Python ports of tidyverse approaches, there's also [siuba](https://github.com/machow/siuba), do you know about it? I have to use this in production, so I'm a bit hesistant about smaller packages. Given the increasing number of related Python libraries I see a big need for tidyverse-like data analysis in Python. There's a difference between production and looking at the data, and I don't think Pandas does a very intuitive job at the latter. It'd be great if all these awesome packages could somehow converge into a bigger thing!

Comment: @telegott `datar` is a new package, indeed. But it does not only mimic the behavior of `tidyverse` APIs, but is implemented by following and comparing to their source code. And it is tested with `tidyverse`'s test cases. There are differences due to the language design, but in most common cases, you are good to go. You are welcome to check out the tests in `datar`, and you will get my points.

Comment: @telegott I know that `suiba` package, and other related packages. `datar` is built upon [`pipda`](https://github.com/pwwang/pipda), which implemented data piping in a different way that is more powerful and easier for implementing a package like `datar`.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this will help but i see you have used a variable called "type", this code might be giving you error because "type" is a keyword and probably not the best choice for variable/column name.. try "type1" or "typ"?
keyword assignment as variable usually doesn't give any problems initially, but later leaves you with inexplicable errors
(im just brainstorming here, i havent used reticulate)

Answer (score 0):

One option is a combination of groupby and case_when:

```py
grp = df.groupby(['w', 'x'])
```

From here, we can run through with chaining and some help from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.case_when.html#janitor.case_when):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

out = (df
      .assign(sequence_id = grp.cumcount().add(1))
      .case_when(
          lambda df: df.sequence_id == 1, 'first', # condition, result
          lambda df: df.sequence_id == grp.y.transform('size'), 'last',
          'other', # default if conditions fail
          column_name = 'position_in_sequence')
      )


out

     w    x    y  z  sequence_id position_in_sequence
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a            1                first
1  1.0  1.0  2.0  b            2                 last
2  1.0  2.0  1.0  b            1                first
3  1.0  2.0  2.0  a            2                other
4  1.0  2.0  3.0  c            3                other
5  1.0  2.0  4.0  d            4                 last
6  2.0  1.0  1.0  b            1                first
7  2.0  1.0  2.0  a            2                other
8  2.0  1.0  3.0  c            3                other
9  2.0  1.0  4.0  d            4                 last
```

You can subsequently get your count:

```py
out.groupby(['position_in_sequence', 'z']).size()

position_in_sequence  z
first                 a    1
                      b    2
last                  b    1
                      d    2
other                 a    2
                      c    2
dtype: int64
```

Another option, with just pandas and numpy:

```py
grp = df.groupby(['w', 'x'])

out = df.assign(sequence_id = grp.cumcount().add(1))

conditions = [out.sequence_id == 1, 
              out.sequence_id == grp.y.transform('size')]
results = ['first', 'last']

out = out.assign(position_in_sequence = np.select(conditions, results, 'other'))

out

     w    x    y  z  sequence_id position_in_sequence
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  a            1                first
1  1.0  1.0  2.0  b            2                 last
2  1.0  2.0  1.0  b            1                first
3  1.0  2.0  2.0  a            2                other
4  1.0  2.0  3.0  c            3                other
5  1.0  2.0  4.0  d            4                 last
6  2.0  1.0  1.0  b            1                first
7  2.0  1.0  2.0  a            2                other
8  2.0  1.0  3.0  c            3                other
9  2.0  1.0  4.0  d            4                 last
```